# Can someone help me clarify my understanding of this regular expression?

Tags: java, regex

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\S+)\\s+(.+?)\\s+(\\S+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("IA HEART RATE 184");
```

So my question is why does the pattern above capture HEART RATE in group 2. Shouldn't '.+' match one or more characters including a space char so shouldn't group 2 capture HEART because it is followed by a space and that should match (.+?)\s+ correct ? So why is it matching HEART RATE?

P.S. I was using matches()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't shown how you're using `matcher`, but I'm guessing that you're using [its `matches()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches%28%29) when what you really want is [its `find()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29). `matches()` needs to match the pattern against the *entire* string, and the only way to do that is for group 2 to be `HEART RATE`. (If group 2 were just `HEART`, then group 3 would be `RATE`, and there would be a trailing  `184` not matched by anything in the pattern.) If you were using `find()`, then group 2 would just be `HEART`, because that's the minimum substring necessary that would allow the pattern to match part of the string.

You also may be misunderstanding what `+?` means. It tries to match as little as possible, while still resulting in a match overall. `(.+?)\s+` is perfectly capable of matching `HEART RATE` ; it's just that it will *prefer* to match `HEART` , as long as that doesn't prevent the rest of the pattern from matching.

Comment: So why does it strip off the space shouldn't space also be captured in group2 or only what is bracketed is always captured ?

Comment: @Phoenix: Re: "only what is bracketed is always captured": Exactly. The `(...)` notation creates a capture-group.